# Почему нельзя с помощью итератора выводить адрес объекта на который он в контейнере указывает

Tags: c++, итераторы

Почему нельзя с помощью итератора выводить адрес объекта на который он в контейнере указывает, если я хочу, скажем, узнать последовательность адресов?

```
int main()
{
    std::forward_list<int> list;
    list.push_front(5);
    list.push_front(4);
    forward_list<int>::iterator it=list.begin();
    cout<<it;
    cout<<*it;
```

Comment: или может быть можно как-то доопределить это действие самому?

Comment: Не ясно с чего вы решили, что это нельзя делать. В коде попыток вывести адрес объекта не предпринимается.

Comment: @user7860670 это в строке cout<<it

Comment: Еще раз: В коде попыток вывести адрес объекта не предпринимается. `cout<<it;` выводит итератор, `cout<<*it;` выводит объект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Итератор - не адрес, но его разыменование дает ссылку на элемент, так что

```
cout <<&(*it);
```

выведет адрес, по которому хранится *соответствующий `int`*.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух"*

Comment: Или без скобок: `&*it`.